# How can I know which formula create this file

Tags: homebrew

```
$ brew link binutils

Linking /usr/local/Cellar/binutils/2.24... Warning: Could not link binutils. Unlinking...

Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/binutils/2.24/share/info/configure.info
Target /usr/local/share/info/configure.info already exists. You may need to delete it.
To force the link and overwrite all other conflicting files, do:
  brew link --overwrite formula_name
```

As I see I can not link binutils because there is configure.info file in my filesystem. 
I am just wondering if there is any way to know which of installed home-brew formulas had installed this file ?

Comment: Could you provide us the content of `configure.info` file ?

Comment: I know that it is a gdb's file (configure.info -> ../../Cellar/gdb/7.7/share/info/configure.info).  But I am searching general way of solving this problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file was installed by Homebrew, it is a symlink to a file in `/usr/local/Cellar/`:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/share/info/bash.info
lrwxr-xr-x  1 admin  wheel  45 Mar 15 15:25 /usr/local/share/info/bash.info -> ../../Cellar/bash/4.2.45/share/info/bash.info
```

It's also possible that the file was not installed by Homebrew. `/usr/local/` is often the default installation target in makefiles, and it is also used by installers and by other package managers like `pip`.